# Java - comparing a string input

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TrueFalseQuiz {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String youranswer;

        boolean answer = false;
        System.out.print("The queens name is Elizabeth? yes or no ");
        youranswer = myScanner.toString();

        String start = myScanner.next();

        {
            if (youranswer.equals("yes")) {
                answer = true;
            }
        }

        if (answer == true) {
            System.out.println("Answer is correct");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Answer is wrong");
        }
    }
}
```

This code doesn't seem to compare the input with the string that I want ("yes" or "no"). I am a beginner and this is just basic code that I'm playing around with.

Comment: As you are the beginner, I would suggest you to read "Head First Core Java" ASAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you have a few things going on here:

- You want to use [Scanner.next()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) or [Scanner.nextLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) to retrieve the input from the end user.
- You want to get rid of that static block of code around the `if` statement.
- You want to compare the answer to any case - if I enter "YES", it will fail.  You can change it to this:

  ```
  answer = "yes".equalsIgnoreCase(youranswer);
  ```

  Since it's a boolean, you don't have to do comparisons on if that value is true, set the variable to true.  You can set it explicitly.
- In the last block, you don't need to compare to `true` in a boolean.  You can simply say `if(answer)`.

Answer (score 5):

While [`Scanner#toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#toString%28%29) *does* return a string, it does not give you anything related to what the user typed in:

> Returns the string representation of this `Scanner`. The string representation of a `Scanner` contains information that may be useful for debugging. The exact format is unspecified.

Use [`Scanner#next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) or [`Scanner#nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29), not `Scanner#toString()`.

---

Note, this is a very basic question which is easily answered by consulting the Java API documentation known as JavaDocs. You should always consult the relevant JavaDocs before posting on Stack Overflow. Your IDE likely has nice built-in JavaDoc, but you can always find the Java SE JavaDocs here, too: http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api.

Comment: But op is using `Scanner#next()` in start variable, I assume if he changes from youranswer to start in if(..) condition, this program should work :)

Comment: Perhaps. But right now that value is just discarded.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Scanner.next()` method or `Scanner.nextLine()`.

The method `Scanner.toString()` gives the string representation of the `Scanner` class.
`Scanner.toString()` actually doesn't read the input text from the console.

Further information,

You can use specific methods which are available in Scanner class, like

```
Scanner.nextShort()
Scanner.nextByte()
Scanner.nextInt()
```

and so on... see [Scanner class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Above method will help you to continue with the input text without formating the text like parsing it to integer and all.